# Graph API token for developer tenent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to access the Online Meetings Graph API (Beta version) using developer tenant. I am able to login successfully to the developer tenant but not able to get the Token to access the graph API for Application type graph APIs. I am able to get the token for delegated type Graph APIs successfully and able to connect to the Graph API. 
I given the admin consent for these APIs using button "Grant admin consent for [0]" in Azure Active Directory => App Registrations => My App => API Permissions in the Azure portal. I am able to see the success message as "Granted for [my Tenant]".

But I am getting the error saying "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application" while getting the token. I am using ConfidentialClientApplication class and AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync method to get the token.

So is there any other place I need to verify for the consent or for developer Tenant and for these Beta APIs, I need to check any other process ?

Thank You for Your Time,
Rishi

I tried for delegated APIs (User.Read and Contacts.Read) and working fine on developer tenant. While doing trail and error I got error saying Invalid Scope (OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All) couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Application type graph APIs, you should use [client credentials flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) to get the token.

Make sure you add the application permission and grant admin consent for it.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response and I have one quick question. I am using the scope resource as https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings/.default for online meetings with the client credentials flow, but getting error AADSTS500011 : Resource principal not found. I  tried with https://graph.microsoft.com/.default scope, and able to get the token with client credentials flow. So could you please suggest am I going in the right direction ?

Comment: Hi Tony, I have to get the token for the scope https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings  to connect onlinemeetings graph api rite? Or can I use the token using default scope to connect OnlineMeetings API?

Getting error while getting the token using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings  (Resource principal not found in the Tenant) or using OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All (Invalid scope).
Do I need to setup anything to use this in my tenant ?

Comment: @Rishi When using client credentials flow with Azure AD V2.0.The scope should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. So your scope should be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. The only thing you need to do is making sure you add the application permission and grant admin consent for it in azure portal.